# nginx upstream load balancing through private networking showing 404

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have two droplets on Digital Ocean. One load balancer with nginx and one node/express webserver with nginx reverse proxy. Let's call them load-1 and web-1. load-1 handles SSL termination and forwards requests via nginx upstream module to web-1 via http over private networking provided by Digital Ocean.

When accessing web-1 on it's public IP everything works. When accessing through load-1 I receive only 404s. I have verified that the requests are actually forwarded to web-1, this is what the nginx access log for web-1 shows on every request received from load-1:

> load-1.private.ip - [09/Jan/2017:13:14:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 404 580 "-" >"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) >Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36"

Why are forwarded requests not working when direct requests are working? Since web-1 is working when accessed directly there must be something wrong with how I forward requests from load-1 to web-1?

**My nginx config on load-1:**

```
    upstream web-servers {
        server web-1.private.ip;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name mydomain.com;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/mycert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/mykey.key;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://web-servers;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
   }
```

**My nginx config on web-1:**

```
   server {
       listen 80;

       server_name web-1.public.ip web-1.private.ip;

       location / {
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, Nginx on web-1 doesn't know what configuration to use.

[Nginx looks at the host header](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) to determine the server configuration to use. You're setting the host to be `mydomain.com` in the proxy settings on load-1, But there's no corresponding entry for `mydomain.com` on web-1.

Either

1. Set the `default_server` flag on web-1 (by changing the `listen 80;` directive to `listen 80 default_server;`)
2. Remove any other `server` blocks so this is the only block (causing Nginx to treat it as the default server)
3. Add `mydomain.com` to the `server_name` list

Comment: I tried all 3 possible solutions:

1. default_server gave me a config error
2. I only had one server block so nothing could be removed
3. I added the load-1 domain/IP to web-1 nginx config server_name and it worked!

I just didn't understand that web-1 was suppose to "broadcast" on the public load-1 IP/domain in stead of it's own IP. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for!  Wasted 6 hours to figure it out on my own.